# Render base64 encoded SVG dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs

I am receiving base64 encoded SVG from API, is there any method to render the decoded SVG in a react app

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const userLogo = () => {
  const logoSVG = useSelector((store) => store.portfolio.logo))
  const [logo, setLogo] = React.useState('');
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
   if(logoSVG)
     setLogo(atob(logoSVG))
  }, [logoSVG])

  return(
    <> { logo }</>
 )
}
```

However while running the above code I am getting the SVG as a string output not rendered value, dangerouslysetinnerhtml prop renders only html format not SVG

Comment: `base64 encoded SVG` meaning string that can be decoded to `<svg>...</svg>`?

Comment: yes you are right, the decoded version is in a string format `<svg>...</svg>`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to convert the text to a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and use the blob as an image element source

```
const blob = new Blob([logo], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```
return <img src={url} />
```

Comment: Great, its kind of a workaround converting the SVG source into url, is there any alternate to render the SVG directly on component?